# Problem starting bash on Ubuntu 23.04, 'Para' command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, 23.04

When I start bash these messages already appear. It started suddenly. I've already looked at the `.bashrc` initialization files and there's nothing related to "Para".

[image]
<sup>**'Para' command not found**</sup>

Comment: Debug your `~/.bashrc` by _temporarily_ inserting `set -x` as the first line. Then, either invoke it with `. ~/.bashrc` or by Logout/Login.

Comment: Obviously one of the files automatically sourced by `bash` contains invalid uncommented line separators e.g. `------------------------` ... Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check them.

Comment: I found the problem, my `.bash_aliases` file had some lines with "-----" that I used to separate my aliases by sectors without being commented out. The strange thing is that in version 22.04 LTS they were also like this and it wasn't a problem (I recently updated to version 23.04). Anyway, the set -x command at the beginning of the ~/.bashrc script was very useful. Thanks!